# How to initialize anonymous inner class in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to initialize anonymous inner class in Java?

For example:

```
new AbstractAction() {
    actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use for example putValue method somewhere in the class declaration?

Comment: what you mean by that? when you say `new` you are already initializing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use an Initializer Block:

```
new AbstractAction() {

    {
        // do stuff here
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
    }
}
```

---

### Initializing Instance Members

> Normally, you would put code to
>   initialize an instance variable in a
>   constructor. There are two
>   alternatives to using a constructor to
>   initialize instance variables:
>   initializer blocks and final methods.
>   Initializer blocks for instance
>   variables look just like static
>   initializer blocks, but without the
>   static keyword:

```
{
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

> The Java compiler copies initializer
>   blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used
>   to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors.

**Source:**

- [Java Tutorial > Initializing
  Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 7):

It's not quite clear what you mean, but you can use an *initializer block* to execute code at construction time:

```
new AbstractAction() {

    {
        // This code is called on construction
    }

    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the instance initialization section:

```
new AbstractAction() {
    {
       //initialization code goes here
    }

    actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just access the variables of the outer class from the inner class.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes#Anonymous_Classes